# Webserver/Flask: Why does an empty url part resolve to the root?

Tags: python, api, rest, flask, webserver

I am using [Restless](http://restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) in my flask app. I make an API resource, doing something like the following...

```
from restless.fl import FlaskResource

class WidgetResource(FlaskResource):
    preparer = FieldsPreparer(fields={
        'id': 'id',
        'name': 'name' 
    }

    ...

WidgetResource.add_url_rules(app, rule_prefix='/api/widgets/')
```

The resource has a list and detail view defined, though they're not shown above. I could include if necessary. Now to the question. In production, I noticed that this route...

```
/api/widgets//
```

returns the same result (though NOT redirecting to it) as...

```
/api/widgets/
```

That is, it's a 200 result, showing the widgets' list view. However, with my development server, the first route yields a 404, as if it is hitting the detail view, like I would expect, and passing an empty primary key. What would cause this discrepancy of behavior on my prod server vs. the dev server?

To be clear, the dev server's behavior is what I am TRYING to get to happen.

Comment: What OS is on each server?  Under the Linux/UNIX family, extra slashes are ignored.

Comment: What server are you using in production (I assume you are using `app.run` in development)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash from the url prefix.

```
WidgetResource.add_url_rules(app, rule_prefix='/api/widgets')
```

Rules typically contain a *leading* slash, so adding the trailing slash creates the two slash behavior you're seeing.  Flask/Werkzeug does some things behind the scenes to handle optional trailing slashes, so that's why they still redirect properly.